# After migration to AndroidX, exception at start up: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "Didn't find class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"

Tags: android, exception, migration, androidx

After migration to AndroidX i have the following exception at startup:

```
LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class               "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.apps.entertainmentsolutions.offhole-yUKw5A4ysDVrPyO-DpnhKg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:217)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5410)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1743)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:460)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:300)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
```

I´m using Android Studio 3.4.1 in Windows 10.

I tried all solutions that I could find, but the problem persists:

[Android design support library for API 28 (P) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782435/android-design-support-library-for-api-28-p-not-working)

[AndroidX Build Fails in Release Mode regarding appComponentFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51006967/androidx-build-fails-in-release-mode-regarding-appcomponentfactory)

I added  -keep class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory { *; } to proguard-rules.pro, i added android.useAndroidX=true and android.enableJetifier=true to gradle.properties... clean, re-built, invalidate chaches and restart...

Disable instant run, too...

Another curious fact, is that I can import the class without problems (import androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory;) from other classes.

My gradle files. Project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {

        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
            }
            google()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
            }
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

App gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "co.offtime.kit"

            minSdkVersion 24
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "4.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        buildTypes {
            beta {
                versionNameSuffix ".beta"
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                zipAlignEnabled true
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
            debug {
                versionNameSuffix ".debug"
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                zipAlignEnabled true
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt' ), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
        productFlavors {
            //main application
            kit {
                applicationId "co.offtime.kit"
                dimension "release"
                versionName "v.kit.4.0"
                versionCode 236
            }
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        }
    }

    def AAVersion = '4.6.0'
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

        annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
        implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

        implementation 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'

        implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.1'
        implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.1'
        implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1'

        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'

        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
        implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.0'

        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'

        repositories {
            maven {
                url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
            }
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Gradle properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Proguard:

```
 -keep class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory { *; }
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_USE_DATA_IN_BACKGROUND" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />

<application
    android:name="co.offtime.kit.core.AppGlobals_"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="co.offtime.kit.SplashScreen_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="www.offtime.app"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ParentActivity_"
        android:label="parentActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name="co.offtime.kit.InitialDataLoadActivity_"
        android:parentActivityName=".ParentActivity_" />

    <activity
        android:name="co.offtime.kit.LoginActivity_"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/login_title"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="co.offtime.kit.NewUserFormActivity_"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/new_user_form_title"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="co.offtime.kit.TestButtonsActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName="co.offtime.kit.DisableHardwareButtonsActivity_">          
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="co.offtime.kit.DisableHardwareButtonsActivity_"
        android:label="disableHardwareButtonsActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="co.offtime.kit.EventListActivity_"
        android:label="@string/event_list_title" />
    <activity
        android:name="co.offtime.kit.EventDetailFormActivity_"
        android:label="@string/new_event_title" />

    <!-- ACTIVITIES -->

    <activity
        android:name="co.offtime.kit.BlockActivity_"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:parentActivityName="co.offtime.kit.DisableHardwareButtonsActivity_"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <service            android:name="co.offtime.kit.core.services.ClosingAppWatcherService_"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />

    <receiver            android:name="co.offtime.kit.core.AvoidCameraUseDeviceAdminReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_policies" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_notifications_white_24dp" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="co.offtime.kit.core.broadcastreceiver.CallBlockerReceiver_">
        <intent-filter android:priority="9999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="co.offtime.kit.core.broadcastreceiver.BootCompleteDeviceBroadcastReceiver_"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="co.offtime.kit.core.services.LaunchBlockJobService"
        android:label="LaunchBlockJobService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

    <service            android:name="co.offtime.kit.core.services.EventExecutorService_"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />

    <service android:name="co.offtime.kit.core.fcmpushnotifications.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service            android:name="co.offtime.kit.core.fcmpushnotifications.FcmTokenUpdateService_"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />
</application>
```

For now this doesn't cause an ANR, the app starts and works normally, but i'm afraid it will cause problems in the future, and i would like to know why that's happening.

Has anyone had this problem? How was it solved?

Comment: This problem just started two days ago for me as well. I made no significant changes to my project structure so I wonder if a problem with an update of some kind is causing this. However, I do not recall updating anything recently.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mike47. But there is no solution? Have you continued developing with the error and haven't caused any problem? That class (CoreComponentFactory) is related to load components from the manifest, I think that omitting it can be risky.

Comment: .@RACSO it seems to compile and run ok, just with that Exception being thrown in the background. I did not remove any components. Would love a solution, not sure if end-users are going to see the same error or not.

Comment: found solution?

Comment: No, i´'m still waiting for a solution, but as i said, it´s seems that the app starts and works normally from final user point of view.

Comment: After testing with dependencies it worked for me. I used (1) instead of (2)
(1)
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
(2)
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'

Comment: any update about this ? I'm having same issue ..

Comment: I have a Pixel 3 and a Pixel 4, both running Android 10 / February 2020 update.. the Pixel 3 throws this exception when installing my app, the Pixel 4 does not. Puzzling.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700486/didnt-find-class-androidx-core-app-corecomponentfactory.

Answer (score 15):

Looks `CoreComponentFactory` class is getting encrypted. Try adding the above class to proguard-rules.

```
 -keep class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory { *; }
```

So the `CoreComponentFactory` won't be the encrypted anymore.

Comment: Made to difference for me. This error is only thrown for me when running espresso UI tests btw.

Answer (score 2):

I hit this error while trying to run a `debug` android app on an AVD emulator.

Wiping the data from the emulator (from the AVD Manager) fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

<s>After reviewing an Android Issue Tracker bug report from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57700486/1992342), I saw a mention about multidex support. I had no multidex flags specified in my project, so I tried setting the flag to false on all modules in my project, and the exception went away.</s>

This was not a permanent solution; the problem returned a few builds later.