# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"

Tags: android, android-apache-legacy

it's a release apk,  and not always to carsh.

happens when i use the firebase to start app in Android P.

it's high rate when first to install the app.

here is the log:

```
2019-06-13 13:28:08.565 23255-23255/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.trackerandroid.trackerandroid-aZ7PnMXyzCxnkBL3b5t3Vg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.trackerandroid.trackerandroid-aZ7PnMXyzCxnkBL3b5t3Vg==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.trackerandroid.trackerandroid-aZ7PnMXyzCxnkBL3b5t3Vg==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:239)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:768)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:847)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1088)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2563)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1792)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7058)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Comment: clean project and rebuild it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AndroidX Build Fails in Release Mode regarding appComponentFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51006967/androidx-build-fails-in-release-mode-regarding-appcomponentfactory)

Comment: @VishalThakkar    it's a release  apk,  and not always to carsh,   happens when i use the firebase to start app.  it's high rate when  first to install the app.

Comment: @LeoLeontev  no the same

Answer (score 0):

Check AndroidManifest file and check application section `"android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"`, if it is written delete it.